# Map markers on a canvas that pop up boxes when clicked

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, canvas

Here's a working version of my code - http://jsfiddle.net/sambenson/g3qsa/#base
How can this be improved upon?

```
$(function(){
    var box = {},
        island = {},
        canvas = {};

    box.el = $('#box');
    canvas.el = $('#arrow');

    function go(el){
        if(box.el.css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
            reset_name();
            $('.island').addClass('inactive');

            box.top = box.el.offset().top;
            box.corner = {};
            box.corner.left = box.el.offset().left;
            box.corner.right = box.corner.left + box.el.width();

            island.el = el;
            island.top = island.el.offset().top;
            island.left = island.el.offset().left;

            island.el.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

            canvas.width = island.left - box.corner.left;
            canvas.height = island.top - box.top;

            canvas.el.css({
                top: box.top,
                left: box.corner.left
            }).attr({
                width: canvas.width,
                height: canvas.height    
            });

            var context = canvas.el[0].getContext('2d');

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 0);
            context.lineTo(box.el.width(), 0);
            context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.closePath();

            context.fillStyle = "#eaeaea";
            context.fill();

            box.el.css('visibility', 'visible');
            canvas.el.show();
        }
        else {
            close();
        }
    }

    function reset_name(){
        $('#name_holder').text('').css({
            top: -9999,
            left: -9999
        })
    }

    function close(){
        $('.island').removeClass('inactive active');
        box.el.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        canvas.el[0].width = canvas.el[0].width;
        canvas.el.hide();
    }

    $('.island').hover(function(){
        if(box.el.css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
            var t = $(this),
                name = t.text(),
                holder = $('#name_holder');
                top = t.offset().top - 60;
                left = t.offset().left - 50;

            holder.css({
                top: top,
                left: left
            }).text(name);
        }
    }, function(){ reset_name(); })
    .click(function(){ go($(this)); })

    $('.close').click(function(){
       close();
    })


})
```

Could it be made faster?
Could it be made more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with @kingjv's suggestions, you can improve the performance of your jQuery selections by making some simply tweaks to the selectors.

Consider if I have the following html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
</div>
```

If you I am using a class selector, such as `$(".cell")` then the selector engine has to do a little more than it needs to. In this example, the selector engine has to walk the entire DOM to match the correct elements.  We can improve this a couple of ways:

- Specify a tag in the selector, e.g. `$("div.cell")`. This allows the selector engine to use the native `getElementsByTagName` method to shrink the number of comparisons the engine has to do to match.
- Specify a root object to start searching from. E.g., if I've previously cache my selector `var root = $("#container")`, I can reuse that selector: `$("div.cell", root)` that way we don't walk the entire DOM for matches.

These are small performance improvements, you'll appreciate them more if you are doing a lot of DOM manipulation and lookup. More simplistic applications won't have such an apparent performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

My comments are more just on style as opposed to performance:

Instead of using :

```
if(box.el.css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
```

it's more readable to use :

```
if(box.el.is(":hidden")){
```

And similarly, instead of using :

```
box.el.css('visibility', 'visible');
```

you can use :

```
box.el.hide();
```

A note on this one though, these are not exactly equivalent because `hide` actually sets `display: none`.  In this case though I believe that's fine.

And one final comment, it's a good practice to name variables which contain jQuery objects with a `$` at the beginning.  This allows you to know that the variable is already a jQuery object without going back in the code to check and avoids accidentally creating jQuery objects out of objects that were already jQuery objects.

So something like this:

```
var t = $(this),
    name = t.text()
```

would become this:

```
var $t = $(this),
    name = $t.text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your review. With regards to your first point: I had to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `.hide()` etc because the jQuery needs to be able to measure the width of the box whilst it's hidden. Your `$variable_name` suggestion is great though!

Comment: Ah okay, I looked to see if you had `visibility` for a reason but missed that.  Can still use `:hidden` though I believe.